# Redux Saga in a loop confusion

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have following (**first**) saga:

```
export function* getIdentificators() {
   while (true) {
      yield take(GetIdentificators);
      try {
         const res = yield call(api.getIds);
         const data = // some array of data

         for (const elem of data) {
            yield put(getAnotherStuff(elem));  <--- calling the second saga in a loop
         }
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see, it dispatches some action in a `for of` loop.
It works just fine, I mean - that saga is being called as many times as `data` length is.

And here comes the **second saga**, responsible for handling that `getAnotherStuff` action:

```
export function* anotherStuff() {
   while (true) {
      const action = yield take(someAction);

      const { actionId } = action;
      try {
         const { data } = yield call(apiCall, elem);

         yield put(someSuccessAction(Action, data));
      }
   }
}
```

So - it doesnt work just right. If I drop `console.log` inside, its being logged only once and only the first result is appearing. So it doesn't work as I want it to be (I would like it to work as many times as I dispatch it in the first saga).

**However**, if I use `takeEvery` instead:

```
export function* anotherStuffWatcher() {
   yield takeEvery(someActionType, anotherStuff);
}
```

It works fine - all requests are being processed.

My final question - Why if I use `while(true)` it processing only the first request instead of every single one? And why does it work properly when I use `takeEvery`? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> its being logged only once

This happens because `call` is blocking effect. Assuming `apiCall` takes some time. So while this call is happening your saga is blocked and is not taking new actions.

```
export function* anotherStuff() {
   while (true) {
      const action = yield take(someAction);

      const { actionId } = action;
      try {
         const { data } = yield call(apiCall, elem); // this is blocking call

         yield put(someSuccessAction(Action, data));
      }
   }
}
```

To avoid this you could either use `takeEvery` helper that takes care of "taking every" action matching the pattern. Or you could use [`actionChannel`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#actionchannelpattern-buffer) that buffers future actions

```
export function* anotherStuff() {

   // buffers up to 10 actions
   // or you could provide another buffering strategy via
   // second argument https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#buffers
   const someChannel = yield actionChannel(someAction);

   while (true) {
      const action = yield take(someChannel);

      const { actionId } = action;
      try {
         const { data } = yield call(apiCall, elem); // this is blocking call

         yield put(someSuccessAction(Action, data));
      } catch(blackhole) {}
   }
}
```

Comment: Im using that `actionChannel` the same way as u wrote it and the same way as it's posted in official docs. Im getting following error: `Error: take(patternOrChannel): argument [object Object] is not valid channel or a valid pattern`. Its strange because Im using the same action as I was using with `take`...

Comment: Ok, u forgot about `yield` before `actionChannel(someAction)`;

Answer (score 0):

**take and call**
You are using *take and call* combination inside the *while* loop. That means, if you dispatch 4 actions. It will run for first action and remaining three actions will be dropped.

> I would like it to work as many times as I dispatch it in the first saga

So there are 2 solutions.

1. takeEvery
2. take and fork combination inside while(true).

As per second solution, just replace 'call' by 'fork' in your code .